# Modal View Controller Size

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

I am trying to display a modal view controller, but keep the navigation bar displaying on the iPad. I've tried the different presentation styles but none work. Is it possible to size it, or display it within right on top of a certain view, instead above the whole view controller?

**EDIT:** *Code added:*

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    RKWebViewController *webViewController = [[RKWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    webViewController.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_link];
    webViewController.webView.delegate = self;
    webViewController.shouldDisplayDoneButton = YES;
    webViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you add some code that you have tried?

Comment: I just have a View Controller, it calls a different class which has a View (or rather, multiple Views stacked). Then in the `ViewController` I just have the `presentModalViewController` on a button click.

Comment: add the code which you are using for presenting modal view, there must be something wrong in that. Have you created the navigation stack?

Comment: Added. Yes I have a navigation stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    RKWebViewController *webViewController = [[RKWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    webViewController.request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:_link];
    webViewController.webView.delegate = self;
    webViewController.shouldDisplayDoneButton = YES;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:webViewController];
    [webViewController release];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
    [navController release];
```

}

Comment: When you present a modal view controller from a subclass of UIViewController, it does not extend the calling navigation controller's navigation bar on modal. So modal view covers the full screen.Check out this thread for detail description on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948023/presenting-modal-view-occasionally-hides-the-navigation-bar

Comment: My `webViewController` changes the done button image using `self.navigationItem`. So the way I had it was, it changes the `navigationItem` but the navigation item has no where to be displayed unless the ViewController is in a Navigation Controller - would that be a correct explanation?

Comment: yes, kind of. View has access to navigation controller, but view covers entire screen so you are not able to see the change.